# What condition am I not fulfilling?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

My criteria is correct, but the first Msg Box is never displayed.  What am i missing?

```
Sub Crr_Premiums()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro all client v.01.xlsm")

    LastRow = wb1.Sheets("CGIBill").range("A:A").Find("Overall - Total", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = 21 To LastRow

If wb1.Sheets("CGIBill").Cells(i, 16) > "0" And wb1.Sheets("CGIBill").Cells(i, 17) = "0.00" Then

MsgBox 1

Else
MsgBox 2

End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried removing the quotes from your conditions?  I think you're looking for the text 0 and not the number 0.

Comment: That was it.  Add that as an answer an I will update the post.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between "0" and 0.  The one wrapped in quotes is checking for a character of "0".  The one without the quotes is looking for the numeric value of 0.  Remove the quotes and you should be good.

Comment: That is it.  Thanks again for the help. Im sure Ill see you again soon.